# Why is my GWT DialogBox Transparent

Tags: css, gwt, user-interface

I want to use a DialogBox within my GWT Application but it is transparent! What do i need to do ?

Comment: Please add some more information about the problem. A little bit of code on where and when you call it? some css or theme used?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the Style in your CSS to be not Transparent, the class shout be gwt-DialogBox.

```
.gwt-DialogBox {
  background-color: #FFFFFF //White
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you included a default gwt theme in your module?. Default gwt theme includes some default css-ing for certain widgets.

```
 <inherits name="com.google.gwt.user.theme.standard.Standard"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it really transparent or are those fields that appear to be seen through it actually in the foreground? I.e. can you click those other fields?

Then it may have to do with the z-index of the dialog box. As a quick and dirty fix, try setting the z-index in the css file or with code like this:
mydialog.getElement().getStyle().setZIndex(1000);